# Visual Studio 2017 só reconhece novo código se reiniciado

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Bom galera, estou tendo um problema com VS 2017 na hora de compilar ou até mesmo na hora de puxar um código via Git...

O VS 2017 só reconhece o código novo se eu fizer algumas das etapas a seguir: fechar e abrir novamente o mesmo, inserir um arquivo (acontece que quando puxo um código via Git, a solução não consegue achar as referencias dos namespaces, dai tenho que criar um arquivo random só pra reconhecimento das referencias e depois excluo o mesmo), limpar pastas Temp do VS.

Acontece que isso é muito chato de fazer, ainda mais ter que fazer isso em toda nova compilação...

Comment: Estava tendo um problema semelhante ao seu, mas quando trocava de branch sem fechar o projeto, o que fazia era renomear os arquivos que não compilavam e ele voltava a reconhecer. Mas nos ultimos dias parou de dar esse problema.

Comment: Ué, você realizou algum update no VS? Por que eu to procurando alguma solução mas não to achando...

Comment: Pior que não atualizei, simplesmente parou de dar o problema.

Comment: Eu to achando que deve ser algum cache de algum lugar... Não é possível...

Comment: Normalmente comigo acontecia em arquivos que eu tinha mechido recentemente no branch, tipo mechia no branch1, ia pro branch2, quando voltava pro branch1 ele dava esse bug.

Comment: Entendi... Já eu mexo numa solução com uns 6 projetos e se eu tiver a audácia de mexer num html, classe, ou qualquer coisa que tenha que compilar pra funcionar, o bendito VS tem que ser reiniciado. Não cheguei a testar se mudar o nome do arquivo e depois voltar ao normal funciona...

Comment: Só por desencargo atualiza pra versão 15.5.. tem diversas melhorias, inclusive de performance  Verifique extensões tb... uma vez o Resharper me deu uma dor de cabeça enorme com cache dele e ficava acusando erro onde não existia.

Comment: @ThiagoLoureiro, cara fui realizando uns testes com o tempo, e realmente, desabilitei uma extensão chamada PowerCommands e o VS parou de dar esse problema... Estranho não? Talvez algo relacionado a verificação de Usings não utilizados? Não sei dizer o que foi ao certo... Mas aparentemente está funcionando.